# Django social auth, linkedin extra values

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I'm trying to use django social auth for linkedin as login for my users. I want to fetch extra values from the users account. I have already mentioned the parameters in my `settings.py`,

```
LINKEDIN_SCOPE = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress','r_fullprofile']
```

But the response I'm getting is only the basic profile information of the user.
How can I get all the mentioned scope information?

Comment: AFAIK you need to call Linkedin API to retrieve the extra values, check Linkedin Docs regarding their API at http://developer.linkedin.com/apis

Answer (score 6):

Something missing in your settings. You should add **LINKEDIN_EXTRA_FIELD_SELECTORS** and **LINKEDIN_EXTRA_DATA** in your setting once you're going to add scopes.

**Example:**

```
LINKEDIN_SCOPE = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress','r_fullprofile']

LINKEDIN_EXTRA_FIELD_SELECTORS = ['email-address','positions', 'headline','summary','picture-url','site-standard-profile-request','public-profile-url','location','interests','skills','languages',]

LINKEDIN_EXTRA_DATA = [('id', 'id'), ('first-name', 'first_name'), ('last-name', 'last_name'), ('email-address', 'email_address'), ('positions', 'positions'), ('summary', 'summary'), ('headline', 'headline'), ('picture-url', 'picture_url'),
 ('site-standard-profile-request', 'site_standard_profile_request'), ('public-profile-url', 'public_profile_url'), ('location', 'location'), ('interests', 'interests'), ('skills', 'skills'), ('languages', 'languages'),]
```

[LinkedIn Developers Profile Fields API](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields)